# Reset counter increment

Tags: javascript, jquery, counter, increment

I have a simple increment counter set up, which is controlled a href value on the page, per click, and updating it. However, as the last section on the page is visited, I want to reset the counter back to the original value of 1.

```
var firstSectionID = $('body .each-section').eq(1).attr('id');
$('.next-section').attr("href", '#' + firstSectionID);

var i = 1;
$('.next-section').click(function() {

    var nextSectionID = $('body .each-section').eq(i).attr('id');
    i++;
    $('.next-section').attr('href', '#' + nextSectionID);

    var numberOfSections = $('body .each-section').length;
    var lastSectionID = $('body .each-section').eq(numberOfSections).attr('id');

    if ($('.next-section').attr('href') == '#' + lastSectionID ) { 
        $('.next-section').attr('href', '#' + firstSectionID);
        alert('last');
            //var i = 1; // I thought adding this would work, but it breaks the code after the first click
    }

});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: " but it breaks the code after the first click" Breaks how? What is the error?

Comment: maybe doesn't work as you expect because you wrote `var i`. Try removing `var` to use the global `i` variabke.

Comment: take the `var` out of `var i = 1` within the anonymous function. that is causing it to create a local variable named `i` within the anonymous function

Comment: Has that been edited out? i see nothing wrong with his usage of `var i = 1` or `i++` (the commented out one is obviously wrong, but it's commented out...)

Comment: @KevinB his use of var i = 1 within the anonymous function creates a local scope variable `i`, which make it so the outer variable i not changed back to 1

Comment: He isn't using it inside the anonymous function though... it's outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove var:

```
var firstSectionID = $('body .each-section').eq(1).attr('id');
$('.next-section').attr("href", '#' + firstSectionID);

var i = 1;
$('.next-section').click(function() {

    var nextSectionID = $('body .each-section').eq(i).attr('id');//*0* eq(undefined) --> fail
    i++;//*1* become undefined++ --> NaN
    $('.next-section').attr('href', '#' + nextSectionID);

    var numberOfSections = $('body .each-section').length;
    var lastSectionID = $('body .each-section').eq(numberOfSections).attr('id');

    if ($('.next-section').attr('href') == '#' + lastSectionID ) { 
        $('.next-section').attr('href', '#' + firstSectionID);
        alert('last');
        i = 1; //*2* if you init i here like var i, on lines *0* and *1* it will be undefined
    }

});
```